# Average of timestamp/Datetime in my query? Please help?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my following sql query.

```
   select a.job_name,endtime,to_char(endtime,'HH24:MI:SS') as endtime_1
   from OPTOOLS.R11_JOB_PROD_VW a, OPTOOLS.R11_JOB_RUNS_PROD_VW b 
   where 
   a.joid=b.joid and a.job_name in ('hh_p_hkc_isrs_gim_trd_ld_bx') and rownum <= 30
   and status = 'SUCCESS'
   order by endtime desc;
```

Please help me in finding the average of the endtime of the above query.I need this urgently.Anybody who is good in sql, can you please modify my query & post it.

I am finding average in timestamp very difficult to handle.

Comment: Your question is tagged `mysql`, but `to_char` looks rather Oraclish to me.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with a help of AVG aggregate finction. But it is not enough. Firstly, you have to convert TIMESTAMP to a number, then use AVG function.

From the manual - *The SUM() and AVG() aggregate functions do not work with temporal values. (They convert the values to numbers, which loses the part after the first non-numeric character.) To work around this problem, you can convert to numeric units, perform the aggregate operation, and convert back to a temporal value.*

So, try something like this -

```
SELECT
  FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(endtime)))
FROM
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: It seems to leave .0000 is there a way to remove the .0000 at the end?

Comment: Your have to specify format to omit fractions: `FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AS datetime`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.job_name, AVG(endtime)
FROM (...)
WHERE (...)
GROUP BY a.job_name
```